# How to programmatically link slack message

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I have a slack bot that is running and can pull information from past slack conversations.  I would like to include links to past messages so that a user can click instantly to a thread.  I have the ts,team,client_msg_id,channel, and user for every message.  How can I construct a link that brings them to the thread.

I have tried

```
https://company.slack.com/archives/{team}/{channel}/?ts={ts}
https://company.slack.com/archives/{channel}/{ts}
https://company.slack.com/archives/{channel}/?ts={ts}
```

Everything I try will redirect me to the correct channel but not to the thread.  There is some kind of id that starts with p that I can see being used but I'm not sure where this value comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to link to messages I would be very careful with reusing some internal syntax you found by inspecting the HTML page. Those are not official. They might work for now, but they might also change at any time.

Instead use the API method [chat.permalink](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.getPermalink) to create a HTML link for a message. You can then use that it as a direct link or link button in a message and be sure it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up these "p" references in the browser version of slack I use.

Here are some links in found using the chrome inspector tool:

Each thread has a "p" reference that is very similar to a timestamp.

```
channel:
https://company.slack.com/archives/chan/p1565761727026300

thread:
https://company.slack.com/archives/chan/p1565794300026800?thread_ts=1565761727.026300&cid=chan

timestamp:
 1565761727.026300

"p" references to 2 separate messages in a thread:
p1565761727026300
p1565794300026800
```

It looks like the *p* are more timestamps that are specific to entries in a thread.
But pasting these links (even if you where able to figure out how to get them) just dumps you in the channel it does not open the thread.

I think that means that even if you had them, Slack won't let you open them in a thread view.

Comment: I was able to figure out my issue. The link format is ```https://company.slack.com/archives/chan/p{ts without .}```Mine was due to that fact that when is was converting the ts value to a string it was removing the trailing zeros so it was breaking.